# Where are cron logs stored on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, cron

I am trying to troubleshoot why my cron task isn't working sometimes.  Where does cron store log files by default?  Is it /var/log/syslog ?

I have looked at that file and it is empty.  Do I need to set something up?

Answer (score 24):

As default, cron's logs saved in /var/log/syslog.
It depends on rsyslogd configuration. You can change it:
Go to rsyslog config

```
cd /etc/rsyslog.d/
```

```
sudo nano 50-default.conf
```

Uncoment line:

```
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
```

Save file and restart rsyslog

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Restart your cron daemon for get it's messages from new file

```
sudo service cron restart
```

Answer (score 7):

When `cron` doesn't work, it'll send out a mail to the user `root`. The only problem is: you don't have the software to send / store the mail in mailboxes.

But have no fear, `Postfix` is here!

## Install Postfix

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postfix heirloom-mailx
```

When install `postfix`, it'll ask you how to you want to setup it up. On the first screen, select `local only` and proceed with the defaults for everything else.

## Configuring Postfix

Now, using your favorite editor, edit `/etc/aliases`. It'll look something like this in the beginning:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
```

What this means is that any mail sent to `postnaster` will now be sent to `root` as well. In this case, we want any mail sent to `root` (for the cron mails and any other system mail) to be sent to `username` (us).

So, edit `/etc/aliases` to look like:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
root:          norman
```

(Replace `norman` with your username obviously. Unless you have the same name/username as me. :) )

After that's all said and done, run the following command to `push` the changes:

```
sudo newaliases
```

Now, after that run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

You'll get the same screen you had before when installing `postfix`. Run through the defaults (`Local Only`, etc..). When you get to the part when it asks for the root and postmaster alias, just make sure it's the same as the one you added to `/etc/aliases` above. Then, continue running through the defaults.

When you're done, run the following command to restart `postfix` and get underway!

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

## Conclusion

Now, if cron has an error, it'll be mailed to you. But, you're probably wondering, how in the world do I check my (local) mail?

To do that, run the command:

```
mail
```

That simple. If there's no mail it'll say `No mail for <username>`. Otherwise you'll get a neat terminal interface to use. See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.html) for information on how to interact with your inbox.

Or, if you prefer, you can access your local man page by using:

```
man mail
```

And now, you're done! :)

P.S. You should read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged) to learn more about the `cron` issue.

Comment: `crond` mails the owner of the job, not necessarily root, so if it is your own job you installed with `crontab -e` then you get the mail.  This is also true whether or not the job "fails"... it simply emails you a transcript of any output the job had.

Answer (score 1):

When running `mail` I got the following response:

```
The program 'mail' is currently not installed. To run 'mail' please ask your administrator to install the package 'mailutils'
```

Instead I found the errors / mails stored in `/var/mail/root`

Answer (score 0):

**#to check all job run timeline**

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
```

**#to check each job full log**

```
cd /var/mail/

ll
-rw-rw----  1 ubuntu mail 9342 Dec 31 07:35 ubuntu

less ubuntu
```

**#in the above file you can find the whole log**

just shift + g so you can see all new logs text

**#to check live file / log update**

```
tail -f /var/mail/ubuntu
```

Answer (score -1):

It is in `/var/log/syslog` by default.

But it can be set up to create a separate cron.log, which is more useful.

This Q&A describes the process:

[16.04: How do I make cron create cron.log and monitor it in real time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-cron-log-and-monitor-it-in-real-time/966195#966195)

Also in this answer is the instructions to create a `wcron` command that displays it is near-real-time.  Plus, it links to another answer,

[How to change cron log level?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949996/how-to-change-cron-log-level/)

that shows how to change the log level to include more than just the start of jobs - level 15 will show errors and end time, also.